# Infinite loop with Beautiful Soup 4 WHILE statement

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull data from YIFY page (as their site lacks some basic filter options) using this short script, but although it works perfectly fine with other pages, it shows no data for this one. In fact, it runs in an infinite loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def praca_crawler(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-" + str(page) + "/"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'mv'}):
            title = link.string
            link_url = link.get('href')
            print(title)
            print(url + link_url)
            page += 1

praca_crawler(4)
```

It seems as if there were two problems here. The while loop (not increasing the page number despite "page += 1" and the filter used for the data.
Would like to get the move titles (without any HTML or CSS tags) and the link.

Comment: is `print(title)` outputting something? maybe try also printing `page`

Comment: yes. It is supposed to print the text from the links under the MV class, which are the titles of the movies

I have tried printing "page" (placed the PRINT statement before the FOR) and somehow it was always 1. The "page += 1" seems to not increment it. I have than removed the incline before the "page += 1", putting it in the same level as the rest of the WHILE statement, than it works (increments the page). But this is wear, as it should work as it is, as this is a copy of working script (just changed the link and class ID).

Comment: `page += 1` should not be inside the `for` loop because you are incrementing the page for every `a` tag that matches, not every page.  Does `print(url + link_url)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def praca_crawler(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-" + str(page) + "/"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        source_code.raise_for_status()
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'mv'}):
            title = div.a.string
            link_url = div.a.get('href')
            print(title)
            print(url + link_url)

        page += 1

praca_crawler(4)
```

out:

```
Kommissar Maigret: Ein toter Mann (2016) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50486/download-kommissar-maigret-ein-toter-mann-2016-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
Love Me (2014) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50485/download-love-me-2014-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
Blood Car (2007) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50484/download-blood-car-2007-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
SS Experiment Love Camp (1976) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50481/download-ss-experiment-love-camp-1976-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
Paper Tiger (1975) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50479/download-paper-tiger-1975-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
The Soft Skin (1964) 1080p
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-1//movie/50477/download-the-soft-skin-1964-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html
```

Problem:

1. put `page+=1` outside the `for` loop, you should increase the number when you iterate over the page, not every time you print a title.

`<div class="mv"><h3><a href="/movie/50486/download-kommissar-maigret-ein-toter-mann-2016-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html" target="_blank" title="Kommissar Maigret: Ein toter Mann (2016) 1080p">Kommissar Maigret: Ein toter Mann (2016) 1080p</a></h3`

2. div's class value is 'mv', not the `a` tag